# how to send data from the layout form to the controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I still confusd abaout the magento 2. I'am new in magento.
my question is How to sending data from the layout form to the controller ?

this my code ui_component/ppp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form.ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form.ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source</item>
    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store list</item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveDuplicateStore" xsi:type="string">Ppp\DuplicateStore\Block\Adminhtml\Duplicate\Store\save</item>
    </item>
</argument>

<dataSource name="ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Ppp\DuplicateStore\Model\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="ppp/duplicate_store/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<fieldset>
    <settings>
        <label/>
    </settings>
     <field name="store" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">  </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <!-- <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl> -->
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">select store</label>
            <dataScope>store</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Ppp\DuplicateStore\Model\Source\Store"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

And this my Controller/Adminhtml/Duplicate/Store/Save.php

```
<?php
namespace Ppp\DuplicateStore\Controller\Adminhtml\Duplicate\Store;
class Save {
    public function execute() {
       echo json_encode("test is true");exit();
    }
}
```

this my DuplicateStore/Block/Adminhtml/Duplicate/Store/Save.php

```
<?php
 namespace Ppp\DuplicateStore\Block\Adminhtml\Duplicate\Store;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

 class Save implements ButtonProviderInterface
 {
 /**
 * @return array
 */
 public function getButtonData()
 {
    return [
        'label' => __('Save kri'),
        'class' => 'save primary',
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => [
                'buttonAdapter' => [
                    'actions' => [
                        [
                            'targetName' => 'ppp_duplicateStore_form.ppp_duplicateStore_form',
                            'actionName' => 'save',
                            'params' => [
                                true
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'sort_order' => 40,
    ];
}}
```

save button inside ui_component/ppp.xml

```
<item name="saveDuplicateStore" xsi:type="string">Ppp\DuplicateStore\Block\Adminhtml\Duplicate\Store\save</item>
```

I tried to show out the text inside json_encode but when I clicked the saveDuplicateStore button only showed 404 not found..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change get button data code like:

```
return [
    'label' => __('Save kri'),
    'class' => 'save primary',
    'data_attribute' => [
        'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
        'form-role' => 'save',
    ],
    'sort_order' => 40,
];
```

After that you need to update your xml part code of 'save' instead of 'Save'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form.ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form.ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source</item>
    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store list</item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveDuplicateStore" xsi:type="string">Ppp\DuplicateStore\Block\Adminhtml\Duplicate\Store\Save</item>
    </item>
</argument>

<dataSource name="ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Ppp\DuplicateStore\Model\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">ppp_duplicateStore_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="ppp/duplicate_store/Save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<fieldset>
    <settings>
        <label/>
    </settings>
     <field name="store" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">  </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <!-- <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl> -->
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">select store</label>
            <dataScope>store</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Ppp\DuplicateStore\Model\Source\Store"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi @Kamlesh Solanki 
I have change it and I got an error `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file C:`

*update
sorry I am forget to close  form tag

Comment: Hi @Kamlesh Solanki 
thanks but its still showing 404 not found.